# Disappearing ProgressBar in Android ListView

Tags: android, list, listview, progress-bar

I'm struggling with a strange problem on Android.

I'v got a ListView with a custom view for list elements. This custom views contains a ProgressBar and a RadioButton. [Here's a nice screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XY3eY.jpg).

Whenever I check a radio, and starts action mode, all the progress bar disappears. [Here's another screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QMO6r.jpg).

If the screen orientation change, or I slide the keypad open, everything goes back to normal.

Now I'v seen a lot of posts about this kind of problems, related to the Adapter recycling views. However, calling `ListView.invalidateViews` does not have any effect. Is there a way to force a full refresh of the whole ListView?

Here's my adapter's code:

```
public class SimpleContactsCursorAdapter extends SimpleCursorAdapter {

    public SimpleContactsCursorAdapter(Context context, int layout, Cursor c, String[] from,
            int[] to, int flags) {
        super(context, layout, c, from, to, flags);
    }

    @Override
    public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {
        TextView nameView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.contact_item_name);
        TextView callView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.contact_call_text);
        ProgressBar progressBar = (ProgressBar) view.findViewById(R.id.contact_item_progress);

        String name = cursor.getString(Contact.Columns.COLUMN_INDEX_NAME);
        int delta = cursor.getInt(Contact.Columns.COLUMN_INDEX_DELTA);
        String callString;

        nameView.setText(name);

        if (delta >= 0) {
            callString = getString(R.string.call_in, delta);
        }
        else {
            callString = getString(R.string.days_late, Math.abs(delta));
            progressBar.setProgressDrawable(mResources.getDrawable(R.drawable.late_progress_bar));
        }
        callView.setText(callString);

        progressBar.setProgress(Math.abs(delta));
    }
};
```

Answer (score 2):

This looks like a recycling problem but it is actually much simpler than that. What happens is that the progress bar drawable looses track of its bounds sets it to 0 and therefore disappears. You can work around it by saving the bounds and the resetting them like this:

```
public class SimpleContactsCursorAdapter extends SimpleCursorAdapter {

public SimpleContactsCursorAdapter(Context context, int layout, Cursor c, String[] from,
        int[] to, int flags) {
    super(context, layout, c, from, to, flags);
}

@Override
public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {
    TextView nameView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.contact_item_name);
    TextView callView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.contact_call_text);
    ProgressBar progressBar = (ProgressBar) view.findViewById(R.id.contact_item_progress);

    String name = cursor.getString(Contact.Columns.COLUMN_INDEX_NAME);
    int delta = cursor.getInt(Contact.Columns.COLUMN_INDEX_DELTA);
    String callString;

    nameView.setText(name);

    if (delta >= 0) {
        callString = getString(R.string.call_in, delta);
    }
    else {
        callString = getString(R.string.days_late, Math.abs(delta));

Rect bounds = progressBar.getProgressDrawable().getBounds(); //Save the drawable bound
progressBar.setProgressDrawable(mResources.getDrawable(R.drawable.late_progress_bar));
progressBar.getProgressDrawable().setBounds(bounds);  //Set the bounds to the saved value
}
    callView.setText(callString);

    progressBar.setProgress(Math.abs(delta));
}    };
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Well cetainly helped me BIG TIME. Thanks sooo much.. I think this should have been the accepted answer to the question.  This behavoiur seems to happen in Gingerbread.  JellyBean was fine.  I had a very similar problem to this basically a progress bar in a listview which was disappearing when the user scrolled down

Comment: Also had issue with it not setting it's self correctly had to reset to 0 then set again using something like progressBarItemRating.setProgress(0);
    progressBarItemRating.setProgress(Item.getRating());

Answer (score 1):

This happens because your `Activity` is destroyed and then recreated whenever there is a change on configuration. For example, if your screen orientation changes, your `Activity` is destroyed and then recreated before displaying the new screen orientation. The problem is that Android does not automatically save the state of your Activity before destroying it. By default, if your `Activity` is destroyed it loses all its data.

To save the state of your Activity you have to manually save your data by overriding `onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState)`. To retrieve your saved data, you need to override `onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState)`.

For a more detail information on how to handle runtime changes, please visit this link: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html

Comment: Thank you for this explanation. However this won't answer my question, which is: why does my progress bars disapear when the `Activity` is NOT destroyed?